# How to merge array of hash based on the same keys in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

How to merge array of hash based on the same keys in ruby?

example :

```
a = [{:a=>1},{:a=>10},{:b=>8},{:c=>7},{:c=>2}]
```

How to get result like this?

```
a = [{:a=>[1, 10]},{:b=>8},{:c=>[7, 2]}]
```

Comment: Me guess that keeping polymorphic values (sometimes 7, sometimes [ 7, 7 ]) is not such a good practice. Why not just keep this in a single hash of arrays rather than an array of hashes whose values are sometimes arrays?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
a.flat_map(&:entries)
  .group_by(&:first)
  .map{|k,v| Hash[k, v.map(&:last)]}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative:

```
a = [{:a=>1},{:a=>10},{:b=>8},{:c=>7},{:c=>2}]

p a.each_with_object({}) { |h, o| h.each { |k,v| (o[k] ||= []) << v } }
# => {:a=>[1, 10], :b=>[8], :c=>[7, 2]}
```

It also works when the Hashes have multiple key/value combinations, e.g:

```
b = [{:a=>1, :b=>5, :x=>10},{:a=>10, :y=>2},{:b=>8},{:c=>7},{:c=>2}]
p b.each_with_object({}) { |h, o| h.each { |k,v| (o[k] ||= []) << v } }
# => {:a=>[1, 10], :b=>[5, 8], :x=>[10], :y=>[2], :c=>[7, 2]}
```

Comment: If you don't mind... Can I use this `(hsh[k] ||= []) << v` in my code? I was looking for this. But couldn't remember anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Minor addition to answer by Arie Shaw to match required answer:

```
a.flat_map(&:entries)
  .group_by(&:first)
  .map{|k,v| Hash[k, v.size.eql?(1) ? v.last.last : v.map(&:last) ]}
#=> [{:a=>[1, 10]}, {:b=>8}, {:c=>[7, 2]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do :

```
a = [{:a=>1},{:a=>10},{:b=>8},{:c=>7},{:c=>2}]
merged_hash = a.each_with_object({})  do |item,hsh|
  k,v = item.shift
  hsh[k] = hsh.has_key?(k) ? [ *Array( v ), hsh[k] ] : v
end

merged_hash.map { |k,v| { k => v } }
# => [{:a=>[10, 1]}, {:b=>8}, {:c=>[2, 7]}]
```

**update**

A better taste :

```
a = [{:a=>1},{:a=>10},{:b=>8},{:c=>7},{:c=>2}]
merged_hash = a.each_with_object({})  do |item,hsh|
  k,v = item.shift
 (hsh[k] ||= []) << v
end

merged_hash.map { |k,v| { k => v } }
# => [{:a=>[10, 1]}, {:b=>8}, {:c=>[2, 7]}]
```

Comment: Arup, your solution is much cleaner than the other two (I don't like flat_map), but you made one mistake. If you try `a = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]`, you will get a nested array. I'm correcting it.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky Can I write now `hsh[k] = hsh.has_key?(k) ?  [*hsh[k]] << v : v` ?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I didn't check that although. :(